# Expected value proof : E(cx)=?

Tags: probability

Let $E(x)$ be the expected value of random variable $x$. $c$ is a constant, then what will be the $E(cx)$ in simplest form and why?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Have you tried to actually calculate $E(x)$ and $E(cx)$ for one or two simple random variables?

Comment: If you use the definition of the expectation in the general case it follows almost directly. $\mathbb{E}[u(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x)f(x)dx$, where $u(x)$ is any continuous functions of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the discrete case:
$$
\mathbf{E} \varphi(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c k p_k= c \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k p_k = c \mathbf{E}X
$$

that's if I understand your question correctly, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a problem with your reasoning.would you kindly explain this to me, why you did not write like this: $E(cx)=\sum x P(cx)=...$

Comment: This is the definition of the function of random variable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables